# Dependecies prefix coding standard

Tags: coding-standards

Running `phpcs --standard=DrupalPractice` in several modules *.info.yml file I get a warning message:

```
All dependencies must be prefixed with the project name
```

I've seen some modules that use the module name as prefix

```
dependencies:
  - modulename:modulename
  - modulename:submodulename
```

Others when it belongs to Drupal core:

```
dependencies:
  - drupal:modulename_already_in_core
```

Others when it belongs to always Drupal (doesn't taking into account if the module is in the core or not):

```
dependencies:
  - drupal:modulename
```

Which is the right syntax? Should I use "drupal" always? Just when the module is in Drupal (core)? What is the aim of this requirement?

Thanks!

More info: https://www.drupal.org/project/coder/issues/2854781

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in [Let Drupal 8 know about your module with an .info.yml file](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/let-drupal-8-know-about-your-module-with-an-infoyml-file), the correct format is:

- project-name:module-name for third-party modules
- drupal:module-name for a core module

> Dependencies should be namespaced in the format: {project}:{module} where {project} is the project name as it appears in the Drupal.org URL (e.g. drupal.org/project/views) and {module} is the module's machine name.

Since the project page for Drupal core is https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal, the case for Drupal core modules is the same as for third-party modules.

Comment: Note that installation profiles do not support this yet. https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2855026